# What are the necessary modules to run Python? (For PyInstaller)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-module

There has been several questions on stack overflow about reducing the size of PyInstaller made exe files. The up-voted answers typically tell you to install only the needed modules however, I have not found a user that has told anyone what those needed modules are. I looked up the docs on python.org but I still have not had much luck. I ran PyInstaller with the option `--log-level=DEBUG` and I attached an image of the modules that are being packaged with my executable file, it's part of the output that comes with the log-level option. I myself have also imported and used:[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmcHW.png)

- Re
- numpy
- warnings
- msvcrt
- edi_load (user-defined)
- ftplib

Would anyone be able to tell me what is the 'barebones' modules needed in order to run Python? For the sake of ambiguity, please don't worry about my individual scripts. I don't mind backtracking Python's standard libraries for the functions I use to see at the top level what's being called. It's the stuff I can't see that I feel I can strip from the program to create a smaller exe file

Research I have already done (I know this is redundant but here it is):

- Stack Overflow
- Python docs from python.org (3.7.2rc1)
- Google

My versions of python / PyInstaller:

- Python 3.7.0
- PyInstaller 3.4

Comment: I *frequently* see people import all of e.g. os, sys, etc. instead of an appropriate subpackage (e.g. os.path). Sometimes they aren't even used at all.

Comment: The answer is almost always "use only what you need".  The documentation from `pyinstaller` suggests that to keep your executable slim, you should make use of venv.  I don't have much experience with that so I can't comment further.

Comment: @JaredSmith we get spoiled by Python's easiness and the computing power of nowadays.  For an everyday script the resource is rarely exhausted to the point you need to slim down so the inexperienced devs (especially those who are students or just using Python as a data analyst tool, etc) just import everything in case they need it for future expansion.  Not a good practice of course, but that's how I see it came about...

Comment: @JaredSmith the problem is that PyInstaller still packages all of os if that was to be done.

Comment: @Idlehands thank you anyways for the information. I'm hoping this could reach one of the python devs that can elaborate what I DON'T need. I will do more research into virtual environments, but the problem is that these executables are meant to be ran on customer facing computers, it seems as if the first articles you find only talk about running the environment on your own computer